# Preloading external flv for FLVPlayback

Tags: actionscript-3, flv, preloader, flvplayback

I have flash actionscript 3 project that on the second frame (after the welcome screen) loads external flv into FLVPlayback component or external mp3 for player.

I'm trying to find code for preloader to the entire project - that will show before the first screen and will preload also the external files so when the user moving to the frame with the player the flv/mp3 will be shown immediately.

is it possible to load the flv into some object and then assign it to FLVPlayBack component as source?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by checking getBytesLoaded against getBytesTotal and creating your own loading bar, but I'd recommend using Greensocks LoaderMax library.

http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/

Lots of info and examples for you to get started.

Comment: that's look good BUT.. to my understanding, it won't work with FLVPlayBack component and my project is already build with it.
if i'm using getBytesLoaded against getBytesTotal will it preload also the external file even if it isn't used in the first frame?